# Middle Mouse Button Not Centered. Bug or WAI?

Tags: 3d-view

So, not a bug per se but I am really annoyed by this.  Whenever I use the middle mouse button to rotate, it loses the centering.  For example if I center on an object using numpad period, when I use the Middle Mouse Button its not centered anymore?

I am hoping this is just a simple thing, but I am afraid of it being just a blender bug.  Its quite irritating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `Orbit around selection` and try with and without `Auto Depth` to see what you prefer:

[image]